# Repeating a string in xparse

Tags: xparse, strings

Is it possible to repeat a string using xparse? I have the following snippet

```
\usepackage[ISO]{diffcoeff}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\lagrange}{\mathcal{L}}

\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\dlangrage}{ O{y} G{0} } {%
    \diffp{\lagrange}{#1}
}
```

For instance `\dlangrange` should render

```
dL
dy
```

`\dlangrange{1}` should render

```
dL
dy'
```

`\dlangrange[x]{2}` should render

```
dL
dy''
```

Is this possible?

Comment: you shouldn't use the G type argument, it has been deprecated and is not recommended any longer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to know, what should I use instead? I was able to solve my problem using `\prg_replicate:nn` =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar either two optional arguments, a key=value interface, or one optional and one mandatory argument.

Comment: Also, please note that `xparse` is only about the argument grabbing, it has nothing to do with repeating strings, that's `expl3` (at least `\prg_replicate:nn` is, of course one could achieve this without `expl3`).